# Downloading pop3 mail attachment with vbscript

Tags: windows, vbscript, automation, windows-server-2008

I am looking for a way to automatically download an email attachment from a pop3 account on a Windows Server 2008. I am limited to using default Windows technology to solve this problem (i.e. not installing additional software or scripting environment).

So far I have selected vbscript as a scripting solution, but struggle with the access to pop3 account. As far as I understood I could use ActiveX/COM or another dll to extend the functionality. Since another dll would mean additional software, this solution is not feasible.

To all you vbscript(-ing) professional: Could you provide an example or a hint on how do solve this download problem with vbscript?

Comment: How is the server receiving POP3 emails, via outlook? Custom mail application? Is it not receiving emails and you'd like to plug in to the mail server?

Comment: It should be accessing a POP3 server on another machine. Currently nothing is on the Windows Server to access the mail account.

Comment: It's not possible to do this with VBScript alone.